# storing tags and levels in two tables, need to get tag for levels returned as columns

Tags: mysql

Hi there
I have big problem with one select query

There is a table:

```
tag_hierarhy
--------------------
|id    |parent_id  |
--------------------
|1     |0          |
|2     |1          |
|3     |1          |
|3     |2          |
|4     |1          |
|4     |2          |
|4     |3          |
|5     |1          |
|5     |2          |
|5     |3          |
--------------------
Comment:
id        - this is the column with tag id
parent_id - this is the id of the tag that is parent of tag with id from column id
One tag can belong to many parents for example: tag 5 belongs to tag 1 and 2 and 3
```

I have another Table with where I keep levels of tags.

```
tag_level
--------------------
|id      |level    |
--------------------
|1       |0        |
|2       |1        |
|3       |2        |
|4       |3        |
|5       |3        |
--------------------
Comment:
id    - this is the tag id
level - this is the tag level in hierarhy
0 - continent level,
1 - country level,
2 - region in country level,
3 - city or village in level 2
```

Now I have to get in one query hierarhy for one tag in one row. For example for tag with id=5 i want to get one row with following data:

```
-------------------------------------------
| tid | l0_tid | l1_tid | l2_tid | l3_tid |
-------------------------------------------
| 5   | 1      | 2      | 3      | NULL   |
-------------------------------------------
Comment:
tid - the id of requested tag
l0_tid - the id of the tag that tag with id=5 belongs to. This tag must be on level=0
l1_tid - the id of the tag that tag with id=5 belongs to. This tag must be on level=1
l2_tid - the id of the tag that tag with id=5 belongs to. This tag must be on level=2
l3_tid - the id of the tag that tag with id=5 belongs to. Thie tag must be on level=3
Imagine for Example tag 5 is pointing to 'Berlin' so:
l0_tid must point to tag 'Europe',
l1_tid must point to tag 'Germany'... and so on
```

I can't change this structure because of many performance reasons. Could anybody help me with query for mysql that will be able to fetch data in the way that i described? I'm fighting with this for all day and my mind go blank. I didn't want subquery only joins. I'm looking for some help. Thanks.

Structure of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE  `street_traveler`.`tag_hierarhy` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_parent_id` (`id`,`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM


CREATE TABLE  `street_traveler`.`tag_level` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_level` (`id`,`level`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t.id                       AS tid, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(d0.parent_id) AS l0_tid, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(d1.parent_id) AS l1_tid, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(d2.parent_id) AS l2_tid, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(d3.parent_id) AS l3_tid 
FROM   tag_level t 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT th1.id, 
                         th1.parent_id 
                  FROM   tag_hierarhy th1 
                         JOIN tag_level t1 
                           ON t1.id = th1.parent_id 
                  WHERE  level = 0 
                  GROUP  BY th1.id) d0 
         ON d0.id = t.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT th2.id, 
                         th2.parent_id 
                  FROM   tag_hierarhy th2 
                         JOIN tag_level t2 
                           ON t2.id = th2.parent_id 
                  WHERE  level = 1 
                  GROUP  BY th2.id) d1 
         ON d1.id = t.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT th3.id, 
                         th3.parent_id 
                  FROM   tag_hierarhy th3 
                         JOIN tag_level t3 
                           ON t3.id = th3.parent_id 
                  WHERE  level = 2 
                  GROUP  BY th3.id) d2 
         ON d2.id = t.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT th4.id, 
                         th4.parent_id 
                  FROM   tag_hierarhy th4 
                         JOIN tag_level t4 
                           ON t4.id = th4.parent_id 
                  WHERE  level = 3 
                  GROUP  BY th4.id) d3 
         ON d3.id = t.id 
GROUP  BY t.id
```

This returns:

```
+---+------+------+------+------+
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 1    | 2    | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 1    | 2    | 3    | NULL |
| 5 | 1    | 2    | 3    | NULL |
+---+------+------+------+------+
```

You need to have indexes on

- (tag_level.id,tag_level.level)
- (tag_hierarchy.id,tag_hierarchy.parent_id)

Comment: The solution above didn't work for me. Also this solution have subquery that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Please check again, I've updated the query and the output. There is no subquery in the above representation just joins on derived tables. It's is efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for help but I get in query browser or in phpmyadmin i get in result blobs for columns l*gid. Every blobs are NULL. The indexes are present :)

Comment: Blobs are expected to show up if the content is large or when the columns is not numerical (Are your columns integers?). Could you please the table schema you have, and sample SQL export of your data to compare.

Comment: I was updated table structure in the question. I notice that when I remove GROUP_CONCAT thet it starts to show proper values :) Why You are using GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: It is used to concat multiple options for the same level, for example Turkey lie on Asia and Europe. And the `group_concat` will return `Asia,Europe`

Comment: I see now. In my project It will be better that database if there are possible some combinations etc europe->turkey and asia->turkey then i would like that database return it as two separate rows or many rows depending on numbers of combination. Thank You very much for derived table idea. You are my databse expert.